# imagemagick caption does not wrap well above font size

Tags: php, fonts, imagemagick, font-size

I have a web application that automatically generates images based on user's specification, and I am working on adding text for the result composition. I am using php with imagemagick and for the text I have chosen cli convert utility because I didn't find any proper support for text wrapping in imageAnnotation

I am using imagemagick convert cli to create the images and then I compose them to the result.

When I try to make the text wrap correctly I see that from a certain font size it doesn't wrap correctly.

For pointsize 20 the text wrap correctly:

```
convert -background  gray  -fill blue   -pointsize 20   -size 100x100  -gravity North  caption:'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 4' ./spikes/20.png
```

will generate this:[image: good text wrapping result]

For pointsize 21 it **doesn't** wrap correctly:

```
convert -background  gray  -fill blue   -pointsize 21   -size 100x100  -gravity North  caption:'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 4' ./spikes/21.png
```

Will generate this:
[image: bad text wrapping result]
***Where are all the numebrs?***

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Should I go for another direction for the text solution?

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. Did you ever resolve this issue?